# How to implement facebook event tracking in Expo App

Tags: facebook, react-native, expo

I am struggling to implement facebook sdk inside my expo app, precisely: I need to track app download campaign, I am following this simple guide from official docs https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/ but events doesn't seem to work. Have anyone succeeded with this?